# zend action helpres usage from the controllers explanations needed

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

can some one tell me how zend action helpers exactly work , i mean , even though i already used them in my code i feel some thing is missing in my understanding :

e.g. i have some thing like this

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setRender('edit',null,true);
```

i my code , so that i will be able to render add-actions to use edit pages (since adding is the same as editing ..... on UI basis @ least )

but my question here is , as far as i can see the _helper is an instance of

```
/**
 * Helper Broker to assist in routing help requests to the proper object
 *
 * @var Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker
 */
protected $_helper = null;
```

but when i try to see in the library folder this class "Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker" i can't find a property named "viewRenderer"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$_helper` is a magical little thing that loads action helpers when needed.  It looks in registered paths - which by default is `Zend/Controller/Action/Helper` - which is where you'll find the `viewRenderer` helper.

The fact that the class doesn't have a `viewRenderer` property is because the HelperBroker handles all requests via the magic `__call` method.

This call method looks for a helper (in this case viewRenderer) and calls the `direct()` method on that helper.

Comment: if i get you correctly does that mean i can call any of the methods found in this path "Zend/Controller/Action/Helper" by making $this->_helper->$one of the classes in that path then ->$any method in that path(i.e. in those classes) (  $$$ params );

Comment: Your understanding is correct.  You'll have to comment on the js answer.. I don't know which one you're referring to.